# Cost of reallocation on changing employer

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

An employee joined a job 2 years ago. Initially, the employer paid him for re-allocation fees as stated in the contract. The contract also states that

"Under our relocation policy, leavers with less than three years of service are required to pay back a proportion of their claimed relocation expenses, at a rate that decreases by 1/36 for every month of completed service."

However, after a year, the employee had an issue with his employer and the employer decided to change his position. Therefore, they decided to terminate the older contract and started a new contract with a continuous date and the probation period is reseted on the new contract. After a year from this, (i.e. after 2 years from initial start) the employee found another job and decided to leave the job. Therefore, the employer made the employee pay for the reallocation fees.

Is this legitimate as the employee signed a new contract where there is no compensation and the probation period was reset? All of this is under UK employment law.

Comment: Have you considered ACAS  https://www.acas.org.uk/ ?

Comment: @rock ape I think it is better to share knowledge here to make the system more transparent and clear to everyone who doesn't know the law system and to those who have same questions.

Comment: Could you change the title to "relocation fees" or better "cost of relocation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do you have a new contract?

If so, the original contract ended (at your request) after 1 year meaning you owe 24/36ths.

### Do you have a variation to the original contract?

This is much more likely.

If so, it ended after 2 years (at your request) meaning you owe 12/36ths.